# Probability of obtaining one infinitely often in a sequence of Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a sequence of Bernoulli trials $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, \dots$, where $X_{n}=1$ or $0$. Assume:

\begin{equation}
P\{X_{n}=1 \mid X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, \dots, X_{n-1}\}\geq \alpha>0, \; n=1,2,\dots
\end{equation}

Prove that:

a) $P\{X_{n}=1 \; \text{for some} \; n\} = 1$

b) $P\{X_{n}=1 \; \text{infinitely often}\} = 1$

Part a) can be solved by conditioning on all possible realizations of $X_{n-1},\dots, X_{1}$ and using and inductive argument.

For part b) it seem easier to prove that the complement of the desired event occurs with probability 0. I have two questions regarding this approach:

1) What is the complement of the event described in b)?, to me it would be the event of $X$ not occurring infinitely often, i.e., $\{\forall n\geq k, \;X_{n}=0 \}$. My confusion arises since it has been suggested to me that the complement is $\{X_{n}=1$ except for a finite number of indices $\}$, which is equivalent to $\{X_{n}=1, \forall n \geq k\}$

2) In any case, the solution of b) revolves around finding the probability of a realization of the sequence $X_{k}, X_{k+1}, \dots$ given the sequence $X_{k-1}, X_{k-2}, \dots, X_{1}$. I need some suggestions about how to proceed here.

Any help would be great.

Comment: There  is probably a elementary argument, but if you are doing martingales/levy-borel-cantelli there is an easy argument

Comment: My confusion arises since it has been suggested to me that the complement is $\{X_n=1 \text{except for a finite number of indices} \}$, which is equivalent to $\{X_n=1,∀n≥k\}$. This is not true. If you are 1 except on a finite amount of indices, you are 1 infinitely often. In fact $\{X_n=1 \text{ except for a finite number of indices} \} \subset \{X_n=1 \text{infinitely often} \} $

Comment: @MrOperator Thanks for the clarification, that argument was driving me nuts.

Comment: @mike In order to use the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, the elements of sequence would have to be independent, this is not explicitly stated in the problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: Mario,  the version  I'm referring says $\sum 1_{A_n} $ and $\sum P(A_{n+1} | X_1,...,X_n)$ converge or diverge together, and is proved using martingale techniques, and I think it throws in Levy's name ad is proved by martingale techniques.

Comment: @mike Sorry for the misunderstanding, I'll check it out. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of any particular answer in a Bernoulli trial of equal probability distribution (flipping a coin, rolling a fair die, drawing a numbered card from a randomized deck with replacement) is $\dfrac{1}{x}$. For our purposes, $x=2$ and so the chance of obtaining $1$ from your trial is $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Given the above, the probability of getting that same answer twice in a row is $\dfrac{1}{2} * \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{4}$. Three times, $\dfrac{1}{8}$. This generalizes to the statement that the probability $P(n)$ of obtaining 1 every time in $n$ trials is $P(n)=\dfrac{1}{2^n}$. By the same token, the probability of *any* of the trials being 1 is the probability that they are *not* all zero (an event which would have the same probability as all trials resulting in 1), therefore $P(X_a=1\ for\ any\ a<n) = 1-\dfrac{1}{2^n}$.

Now we extend this to the infinite. We can't say $n=\infty$; that's nonsensical. What we can say is that these equations converge as $n\to \infty$; $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^n} = 0$, and so $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1-\dfrac{1}{2^n} = 1$. In English, we will *almost surely* see at least one 1 in the series of infinite trials, and we will *almost surely not* see an infinite sequence of 1s. It's not *impossible* for us to never see a 1, or for us to never see a 0. These events simply occur with probability zero.

Comment: Of course I agree with you. However, I think that the point of the problem is to prove that the reasoning you expose is true even if we look at the sequence at some point k > 1, intuitively this is certain. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also note that we don't know for certain that $P\{X_{n} = 1\} = P\{X_{n} = 0\}$